# jQuery.ajax() don't fire handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying load json file (from localhost) named `questions.json` by function:

```
function loadJson() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "questions.json",
        succes: function() {
            console.log("ajax succes");
        },
        error: function(object, error, errorThrow) {
            console.log("ajax fail");
            console.log(object);
            console.log(error);
            console.log(errorThrow);
        }

    });

}
```

and i run function in my script `$(document).ready(loadJson());`

In developer tools in Google Chrome looks everything OK (Status Code 200, preview shows valid json...), but console.log in both functions (succes and error) dont't write nothing. There aren't any other error messages.

If I change dataType to `nonsense`, function in error is fired.

What could be wrong?

Comment: side note: `$(document).ready(loadJson());` should be `$(document).ready(loadJson);`

Comment: are you looking at the logging tab on your console ?

Comment: and `succes: function() {` should be `success`.

Comment: By JSHint in jsfiddle is code perfect valid. My mistake. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

*What could be wrong?*

seems to be a typo with your ***`success`*** callback:

```
succes // <---missing a 's' in success
```

change to this:

```
success:function(){}
```